# Java Regex Matching, 2 simple regex questions

Tags: java, regex

**Question 1.**

```
String matchedKey = "sessions.0.something.else";
Pattern newP = Pattern.compile("sessions\\.([^\\.]+)(\\..+)");
m = newP.matcher(matchedKey);

System.out.println(m.group(1)); // has nothing. Why?

sessions\\. // word "sessions" followed by .
([^\\.]+)   // followed by something that is not a literal . at least once
(\\..+)     // followed by literal . and anything at least once
```

I would have expected for m.group(1) to be 0

**Question 2**

```
String mask = "sessions.{env}";
String maskRegex = mask.replace(".", "\\\\.").replace("env", "(.+)")
                                   .replace("{", "").replace("}", "");
// produces mask "sessions\\.(.+))"
```

When used as

```
Pattern newP = Pattern.compile("sessions\\.(.+))"); // matches  matchedKey (above)
Pattern newP = Pattern.compile(maskRegex);          // does not match matchedKey (above)
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

before you can access the groups of a matcher, you have to call `matches` on it:

```
String matchedKey = "sessions.0.something.else";
Pattern newP = Pattern.compile("sessions\\.([^\\.]+)(\\..+)");
m = newP.matcher(matchedKey);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

`find` will also do if you want to find the pattern anywhere within the string. `matches` checks if the whole string matches your pattern from the beginning to the end.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't called `Matcher.find()` OR `Matcher.macthes()` method in your both questions.

Use it like this:

```
if (m.find())
   System.out.println("g1=" + m.group(1));
```

Also good to check `Matcher.groupCount()` value.